# JavaFX: Our javascript file is not working when we build the html and put the link in header. Why is this?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, javafx

The user should be able to change the value and the numbers should change. 
What is wrong in this situation? Also is it possible to link the JS file in the html to run in a JavaFX webView?

```js
var numbersToChange;
var multiplier;

function pageLoad() {
  var inputBox = Number(document.getElementById("servingInputBox").value);
  multiplier = new Array();
  numbersToChange = document.getElementsByClassName("numberToChange");

  for (i = 0; i < numbersToChange.length; i++) {
    multiplier[i] = Number(numbersToChange[i].innerHTML) / inputBox;
  }
}

function changeNumbers() {
  var inputboxValue = Number(document.getElementById("servingInputBox").value);

  for (i = 0; i < numbersToChange.length; i++) {
    numbersToChange[i].innerHTML = (Math.trunc((inputboxValue * multiplier[i]) * 10)) / 10;
  }
}

function increase() {
  var inputBox = Number(document.getElementById("servingInputBox").value);

  document.getElementById("servingInputBox").value = (Math.trunc(inputBox * 10) + 10) / 10;

  changeNumbers();
}

function decrease() {
  var inputBox = Number(document.getElementById("servingInputBox").value);
  var newNumber = (Math.trunc(inputBox * 10) - 10) / 10;

  if (newNumber >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("servingInputBox").value = newNumber;
    changeNumbers();
  }
}

function enter(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    var inputBox = Number(document.getElementById("servingInputBox").value);

    document.getElementById("servingInputBox").value = Math.trunc(inputBox * 10) / 10;

    changeNumbers();
  }
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Archivo Black';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Archivo Black Regular'), local('ArchivoBlack-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/archivoblack/v4/WoAoVT7K3k7hHfxKbvB6B6GwZwAVuVwqynDPq0VH9Ho.woff2) format('woff2'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/archivoblack/v4/WoAoVT7K3k7hHfxKbvB6B0BTuPGxyeV-VBVV8KqqzrI.woff) format('woff');
}


html,body{
 margin:0 0 1px;
 padding:0
}

input,textarea{
 background-color:white
}

html{
 overflow-y:scroll;
 height:100%
}

body{
 font-family:'Open Sans',sans-serif;
 font-size:11px;
 color:#202020;
 line-height:14px;
 position:relative;
 padding-bottom:50px;
 background-repeat:repeat-x;
 background-position:0 -298px;
 background-color:white
}

.nutritionLabel{
 font-size:115% !important
}

@import url("//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Archivo+Black");

.nutritionLabel input.unitQuantityBox.ui-shadow-inset{
 box-shadow:none
}

.nutritionLabel{
 font-size:90%;
 margin-bottom:1.1em;
 padding:.68em;
 color:#333;
 font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
 border:2px solid #000;
 line-height:normal
}

.nutritionLabel .title{
 line-height:.83em;
 font-size:2.7em;
 padding-bottom:4px;
 font-family:'Archivo Black';
 white-space:nowrap;
 letter-spacing:-2px
}

.nutritionLabel .m{
 font-size:.9em
}

.nutritionLabel .serving{
 font-size:1.1em;
 line-height:1.28em;
 padding-bottom:2px
}

.nutritionLabel .name{
 font-size:1.1em;
 line-height:1.3em
}

.nutritionLabel .name.inline{
 padding-top:.2em;
 padding-top:.25em \9
}

.nutritionLabel .dvCalorieDiet,.nutritionLabel #calcDisclaimer{
 font-size:.9em
}

.nutritionLabel .line{
 border-top:1px solid #333;
 padding:1px 0
}

.nutritionLabel .line.last{
 border-bottom:1px solid #333
}

.nutritionLabel .line.indent{
 margin-left:15px
}

.nutritionLabel .dv{
 float:right
}

.nutritionLabel .dv:before{
 content:'\0000a0'
}

.nutritionLabel .bar1{
 height:10px;
 line-height:0;
 font-size:1px;
 background:#333
}

.nutritionLabel .bar2{
 height:5px;
 line-height:0;
 font-size:1px;
 background:#333
}

.nutritionLabel .dvCalorieDiet{
 color:#777
}

.nutritionLabel .calorieNote{
 padding:.60em 0 0 .70em
}

.nutritionLabel .star{
 margin-left:-7px
}

.nutritionLabel .tblCalorieDiet th{
 font-size:.7em;
 border-bottom:1px solid #333;
 text-align:left;
 color:#777
}

.nutritionLabel .tblCalorieDiet{
 width:100%
}

.nutritionLabel .tblCalorieDiet td{
 padding:0;
 line-height:normal;
 font-size:.7em;
 color:#777
}

.nutritionLabel .ar{
 text-align:right
}

.nutritionLabel .fr{
 float:right
}

.nutritionLabel .fl{
 float:left
}

.nutritionLabel #calcDisclaimer{
 color:#777
}


.nutritionLabel .spaceAbove{
 height:10px
}

.nutritionLabel .setter{
 width:12px;
 padding:3px 0 0 0;
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 z-index:100
}

.nutritionLabel .setter a{
 display:block;
 width:9px;
 height:7px;
 font-size:1px;
 line-height:0em
}

.nutritionLabel a.unitQuantityUp{
 padding-bottom:1px;
 background:transparent url("up.png") left top no-repeat;
 z-index:9999
}

.nutritionLabel a.unitQuantityDown{
 padding-top:1px;
 background:transparent url("down.png") left bottom no-repeat;
 z-index:9999
}

.nutritionLabel input.unitQuantityBox{
 width:25px;
 height:22px;
 padding:2px;
 font-size:.9em !important;
 margin-left:15px;
 margin-bottom:0;
 line-height:15px \9
}

.nutritionLabel input.unitQuantityBox.arrowsAreHidden{
 margin-left:0
}

.nutritionLabel .rel{
 position:relative
}

.nutritionLabel .servingSizeField{
 float:left;
 margin-top:.2em;
 margin-bottom:.2em;
 margin-right:.4em
}

.nutritionLabel .servingUnit{
 float:left;
 padding:0;
 margin-top:.3em;
 margin-bottom:.2em
}

.nutritionLabel .servingWeightGrams{
 padding:0 0 0 .3em;
 margin-top:.3em;
 margin-bottom:.2em
}

.nutritionLabel .servingSizeText{
 padding-right:.3em;
 margin-top:.3em
}

.nutritionLabel .servingUnitQuantity{
 margin-top:.3em;
 padding-right:.3em
}

.cf:before,.cf:after{
 content:" ";
 display:table
}

.cf:after{
 clear:both
}

.cf{
 *zoom:1
}

.nutritionLabel .servingSizeText{
 display:inline-block
}

.nutritionLabel .line{
 line-height:normal;
}

.nutritionLabel .title{
 padding-bottom:6px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body onload="pageLoad()">
  <div class="nutritionLabel" style="width: 283px;">
    <div class="title">Nutrition Facts</div>
    <div class="name">Ice Cream</div>
    <div class="serving">
      <div class="cf">
        <div class="servingSizeText fl">Serving Size:</div>
        <div class="rel servingSizeField fl">
          <div class="setter">
            <a href="javascript:increase()" class="unitQuantityUp" rel="nofollow"></a>
            <a href="javascript:decrease()" class="unitQuantityDown" rel="nofollow"></a>
          </div>
          <input value="1" id="servingInputBox" class="unitQuantityBox" type="text" onkeypress="enter(event)">
        </div>
        <div class="servingUnit fl unitHasTextbox">pizza</div>
        <div class="servingWeightGrams fl gramsHasTextbox">(853g)</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="line m"><b>Amount Per Serving</b>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="fr">Calories from Fat <span class="numberToChange">740</span>
      </div>
      <div><b>Calories</b>  <span class="numberToChange">2270</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="line ar"><b>% Daily Value<sup>*</sup></b>
    </div>
    <div class="line">
      <div class="dv"><b><span class="numberToChange">128</span></b>%</div><b>Total fat</b><span class="numberToChange"> 83</span>g</div>
    <div class="line indent">
      <div class="dv"><b><span class="numberToChange">190</span></b>%</div>Saturated Fat<span class="numberToChange"> 83</span>g</div>
    <div class="dvCalorieDiet line">
      <div class="calorieNote"><span class="star">*</span>Percent Daily Values are based on a 2000 calorie diet.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please help if you have any knowledge on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

Please include the javascript file in the head. Also the css does not load i suppose. 
The structure of the head is to be as follows.

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>ABC</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/app.css"/>
<script src="js/app.js"></script></head>
```

Also, parallel to the path of your HTML file, create folders for 'style' and 'js' and insert the js and css files in the folders by names 'app.css' and 'app.js'
This should do your job.

Comment: For this example I did not add that in but it is like that on our html file. Even when you run the code snippet it does not work.

Comment: Have you checked developers tool-console for any errors?

Comment: Please share a fiddle.